# Run all applications with VirtualGL on TurboVNC

Tags: virtualgl

Is there a way to run all applications on my TurboVNC server with VirtualGL instead of TurboVNC's built in implementation? I need the GLX extension and it won't work with the TurboVNC server. I need to run Steam. If I start Steam with `vglrun steam`, it starts, but the daemon can't stay up because it doesn't have the GLX extension. If I start Steam without `vglrun`, it just doesn't work (same error, but even sooner).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with the launch option `-vgl` for the TurboVNC server. **Don't** use the GLX extension via `-extension GLX`.